# Convert Javascript object to array of numbers

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have an object which has a set of numbers

```
> var size = d3.values(data[0]);

>size
output:
["0", "14.71", "50.0", "35.29"]

>typeof(size);
output:
"object"
```

I want to sum up the width and get an output like below:

> [0, 14.71, 64.71, 100]

But the output which I got is as below:

```
>var width = [size[0],
                    size[0]+size[1],
                    size[0]+size[1]+size[2],
                    size[0]+size[1]+size[2]+size[3]];

>width
output:
["0", "014.71", "014.7150.0", "014.7150.035.29"]
```

Please help me fix this. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and thisArgs and an implicit casting to number for the element.

```js
var data = ["0", "14.71", "50.0", "35.29"],
    width = data.map(function (a) {
        return this.count += +a;
    }, { count: 0});

console.log(width);
```

ES6 without use of thisArg (`this` would not work with an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)), but with a closure of `count`.

```js
var data = ["0", "14.71", "50.0", "35.29"],
    width = data.map((count => a => count += +a)(0));

console.log(width);
```

Comment: Wow! `Array` seem to be your special _friend_ :)

Comment: @NinaScholz Since the question is pretty straightforward, the real **Wow** goes to your use of the second argument of `.map()` to introduce an interim counter variable. That's a nice idea to avoid cluttering the outer scope with yet another variable! I am definitely going to resort to this for future applications.

Comment: @altocumulus, it's just a pattern to overcome the `this` problem (as temp variable) with arrow functions.

Comment: @NinaScholz I was talking about explicitly specifying the `this` argument within the call to `.map()` just for the sake of keeping track of the count in your ES5 snippet. This pattern may be so obvious to you that you won't find it worth mentioning, but it never occured to me to use it like this. Nicely done!

Comment: @NinaScholz And a nice example of floating point mania, because the third value of the result is strictly speaking not the value requested by OP ;-)

Comment: you could use, in this case `data.map((count => a => +(count += +a).toFixed(2))(0));`.